# QGIS: Spatial extrapolation

Tags: qgis, interpolation, kriging, extrapolation

I have few sample points with values on (agricultural) field and I want to interpolate and extrapolate values inside the field boundary.

Ideally I would like to use Kriging (as it smooths local extrem values). I can't use all point to make one big raster and then clip out every polygon, but I need to calculate separate raster for every single polygon.

Is there please any tool or plugin to extrapolate values within polygon boundary? It was asked before, but there were no sufficient answer.

[image]

Comment: You cannot use kriging (or any interpolation for that matter) with only 3 or 4 points per polygon.

Comment: I see. So please is there any way how to perform this with any other method: IDW, spline, etc.?

Comment: Well, I should not have said "cannot use...". You **can perform** any method you choose, but you should be very suspicious of the results, with so few data points.

Comment: For example, one of your polygons has a single data point. How would you want to "interpolate" across that field with only one point value?

Comment: Then I should use "fill the raster inside polygon with combination of point values" instead of interpolation. I mean, when there is one point, then the whole polygon will have one constant value, if there are two point, neighboring pixels will have the value of point and somewhere at the center of the connecting line the value will be point's average. I just want to fill the polygon with raster and somehow take in the account values of points.

Comment: I can't say what you "should" use. I'm not sure what you are referring to in: "fill raster inside polygon...". But this will not do any kind of interpolation. All raster pixels within each polygon will get the same value, determined by some statistic from the points inside that polygon: mean, min, max, median, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found solution, but unfortunately only for ArcMap. And yes - extrapolation is not an accure method, but it is better than nothing if there is no other solution (so be aware about interpretation of values).

Use Toolbar *Geostatistical Analyst* in ArcMap (tool *Geostatistical Wizzard*) and run selected interpolation method (ex. Kriging). Go to *Properties* of the new raster to tab *Extent* and in column **Set the extent to:** use the option **the rectangular extent of „boundary polygon“**. Done.